# New Python Programmer - trying to add a ValueError exception to a number guessing game

Tags: python

I'm working through the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python Course on YouTube/udemy, and I'm on a lesson that covers a simple number guessing game. [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48WXHT0dfEY)

The code itself I more or less understand:

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

print('Hello. What is your name?')
name = input ()

print('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between one and a ONE HUNDRED.')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 100)

for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')

    if guess < secretNumber: 
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    else:
        break # This condition is for correct guesses!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job, ' + name + ', You took ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber) + '. You Failed!')
```

You take a random integer between 1 and 100. The user tries to guess it. If they get it right, it tells you. If you're unable within a certain number of guesses, you lose.

I wanted to add a 'try' 'except' statement to deal with a non-integer input that the user might make. It took me a while to get around the syntax errors, but I managed to write:

```
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    try: 
        guess = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print ("That's not an integer!")
    if guess < secretNumber: 
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    else:
        break # This condition is for correct guesses!
```

This produces the correct error message. However, it produces another 'NameError' because guess is now not properly defined.

How should I amend the flow statements to get me back to the point where the program allows me to input a different value?

Comment: You can use **`while True`** to wrap `try except` and use **`break`** at the end of the try block

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you catch the exception in your `except` statement, execution continues into the following `if` expression, at which point you get your `NameError` because `guess` isn't defined (because the assign statement raised a `ValueError` exception).

If the user enters an invalid input, you problem just want them to try again. That's what the `continue` statement is for:

```
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    try: 
        guess = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print ("That's not an integer!")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the loop is continuing after printing "That's not an integer". Use a continue statement to solve this problem.

```
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
print('Take a guess.')
try: 
    guess = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print ("That's not an integer!")
    i -= 1
    continue // Returns to start of loop without executing the rest of it
if guess < secretNumber: 
    print('Your guess is too low.')
elif guess > secretNumber:
    print('Your guess is too high.')
```

I've also added `i -= 1` to reduce i by one. This is so that the user's number of guess left does not change in case they accidentally type a letter.